# How to create scope in Laravel 5.4 on *belongsToMany* table connection?

Tags: php, laravel, scope, eloquent, laravel-5.4

The table scructure looks like this:

```
person
   id - integer
   name - string

company
   id - integer
   name - string

person_company
   person_id - integer
   company_id - integer
```

Here is the models:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'person_company');
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person', 'person_company');
    }
}
```

Which means, one person can be part of multiple companies and each company can have many persons;

On the standard `Laravel` *users* table, we have:

```
users
   id - integer
   name - string
   company_id - integer
```

Where each user belogs to a company.

---

**[PROBLEM 1]**

How to create a *scope* to only bring the persons that belong to an specific company?

I tried to use *GlobalScope*:

```
class CompanyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $model->companies()->where('company_id', 1);
    }
}

class CompanyScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $query->companies()->where('company_id', 1);
    }
}
```

But couldn´t get it through... I also tried *LocalScopes*:

```
public function scopeCo($query, $company_id)
{
    return $query->companies()->where('company_id', $company_id);
}
```

No success...

---

**[PROBLEM 2]**

Another thing to point out is the option to send a variable to the *scope* as of the *local scope* sample code above, where receive the `company_id` ($company_id) from user through the *`controller`*, using `Auth::user()->company_id;`.

What I expect to use on the *controller* was that my *Local Scope* would return the people linked to the users company, as of:

```
Person::Co(Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
```

Has anyone implemented this kind of *scope*, yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to query the related table.

```
public function scopeCo($query, $company_id)
{
    $query->whereHas('companies', function ($query) use ($company_id) {
        $query->where('person_company.company_id', $company_id);
    });
}

Person::Co(Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
```